# JAWS scrollable content issue

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I'm working on building a accessible website in which we have a web page where upper half part of web page is taken by an image and lower half part of website is a scrollable region where we can navigate through website and use it.
When I navigate through website using JAWS and arrowkeys it scrolls the content perfectly while navigating down, but when I try to navigate back at the top of the page, it doesn't scrolls properly and JAWS focuses on the elements which are behind the static image at the top.
How to make sure that the focused content is visible on the screen and not behind the image?
[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt8Nk.jpg) for reference.

Edit 1: I tried adding tabindex='0' attribute and also by adding anchor tags inside the scrollable content as suggested in https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/act/rules/0ssw9k/proposed but it didn't worked for me.

Below is the sample code and the link for the page where we can test the issue with JAWS and navigating through arrow keys

https://www.w3.org/WAI/content-assets/wcag-act-rules/testcases/0ssw9k/89302c4f9eaf142418751a45e6dd025d5d294591.html

```
<section style="height: 100px; width: 500px; overflow: scroll;" tabindex="0">
    <h1>WCAG 2.1 Abstract</h1>
    <p>
        Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.1 covers a wide range of recommendations for making Web content more
        accessible. Following these guidelines will make content more accessible to a wider range of people with
        disabilities, including accommodations for blindness and low vision, deafness and hearing loss, limited movement,
        speech disabilities, photosensitivity, and combinations of these, and some accommodation for learning disabilities
        and cognitive limitations; but will not address every user need for people with these disabilities. These guidelines
        address accessibility of web content on desktops, laptops, tablets, and mobile devices. Following these guidelines
        will also often make Web content more usable to users in general.
    </p>
</section>
```

Comment: Could you post a link to a test page reproducing the issue ? Thank you.

Comment: Is this issue reproducible in a different browser? And without JAWS? When you say “navigating”, do you mean by means of arrow keys when the scroll container is focussed, or by means of Shift+Tab? Thanks

Comment: @QuentinC I've added the sample code and link of the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Andy I've tested only in Chrome and Edge and it is reproducible in both the browsers

Comment: And without JAWS?

Comment: @Andy I've tested with JAWS and Windows screen narrator and it works perfectly fine with Windows screen narrator but not works with JAWS. And by navigating I mean navigating using arrow keys, since we don't have option to use "Tab" and "Shift + Tab".

Comment: Does *Page Down* work when the section has focus?

Comment: @Andy by the page down do you mean scroll down or navigation down?
Navigation down works properly with JAWS and arrow keys but navigating up doesn't scroll the page.

Comment: Ah right. I mean the key *Page Up*, and the key *Home*. Do they work to scroll back up?